# pivoting three XML values using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, pivot

I have an XML file which has 3 columns.

User_Created
Controlled_Drug_Name
count

I would like to PIVOT this using XSLT so that one column is the row headinhgs, one is the rows and the other is the data.

E.e.

I want the User_Created along the top row, Drugs going down and then the count of each in the pivot table.

I have the following so far which does the names and drugs but the counts are not populated.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright Strand Technology Ltd, 2008 -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:cn="http://www.strandtechnology.co.uk/carenotes" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="UserHeader" match="QueryResults/Data/DataRow" use="User_Created" />
  <xsl:key name="DrugHeader" match="QueryResults/Data/DataRow" use="Controlled_Drug_Name" />
  <xsl:template match="QueryResults">
    <table>
      <tr style="text-align:center;">
        <td>DRUG NAME</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="Data/DataRow[count(. | key('UserHeader', User_Created)[1]) = 1]">
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="User_Created" />
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Data/DataRow[count(. | key('DrugHeader', Controlled_Drug_Name)[1]) = 1]">
        <tr style="text-align:center;">
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Controlled_Drug_Name" />
          </td>
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/DataRow[count(. | key('UserHeader', User_Created)[1]) = 1]">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count" />
                    </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide part of the XML as example, it's just a guess. But in case the name of the node/column in the input XML is `Count`, it could work if you change

```
<xsl:value-of select="count" />
```

into

```
<xsl:value-of select="Count" />
```

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, the column name is count, so it's not an issue of the naming. I've just created an example input, not knowing if this matches the actual input, with a different approach to get the table.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <QueryResults>
    <Data>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 1</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 1</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>1</count>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 2</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 2</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>2</count>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 3</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 3</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>3</count>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 1</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 3</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>4</count>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 2</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 3</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>5</count>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <User_Created>user 2</User_Created>
            <Controlled_Drug_Name>name 4</Controlled_Drug_Name>
            <count>5</count>
        </DataRow>
    </Data>
  </QueryResults>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kUsers" match="User_Created" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="kRowByName" match="DataRow" use="Controlled_Drug_Name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="users" select=
      "//User_Created
      [generate-id()
      =
      generate-id(key('kUsers', .)[1])
      ]
      "/>
  <xsl:template match="QueryResults">
     <html>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$users"/>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=
                "//DataRow
                [generate-id() = 
                 generate-id(key('kRowByName', Controlled_Drug_Name))]">
                <xsl:sort select="Controlled_Drug_Name"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </tbody>
       </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="User_Created">
    <th>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DataRow">
    <tr>
       <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="Controlled_Drug_Name"/>
       </td>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$users" mode="row">
          <xsl:with-param name="nRows"
           select="key('kRowByName', Controlled_Drug_Name)"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="User_Created" mode="row">
    <xsl:param name="nRows"/>
    <td>
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "$nRows[User_Created=current()]/count"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
<table>
  <thead>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>user 1</th>
     <th>user 2</th>
     <th>user 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>name 1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>name 2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>name 3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>name 4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Maybe you can use this approach to work with the actual input.

Comment: Sorry for not doing that, the data is quite sensitive so I didnt want to add it here. But the count column name has a small case c as in my example.  Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: I feel like the count will need a combination of the two keys somehow?

Comment: @user3284707 Yes. Just updated my answer with some example input and an adjusted approach.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I am after.. Genuius!!